# Understanding how to formally use the definition of stopping time to prove something is a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

In my notes I have the following definition
**A random variable $T=0,1,2,...,\infty$ is a stopping time , if $\forall n \le \infty$, the event $\{T \le n\}\in \mathscr F_n$**

There are several examples (about martingales) where they first say something is a stopping time, so I just report here that initial part

1 The time $T$ of the first Head in a sequence of coinflips is a stopping time, while the time one before the first Head is not

2 A monkey repeatedly types any of the 26 letters of the English alphabet independently with
equal chance. Let $T$ be the number of letters that have been typed when the entire word “ABRACADABRA” first appears. $T$ is a stopping time

3 Let $ X_k$ be iid ±1-valued with equal chance. The sum $S_n = \sum_{ k=1}^n X_k$ is called simple symmetric random walk (SSRW). Empty sums are zero, hence $S_0 = 0$. Then $S_n$ is a martingale, and $T : = \inf\{n : S_n = 1\}$ is a stopping time in the natural filtration of the walk

**In all of these examples no clear explanation is given on how to prove that T is a stopping time. All they argue is that "using T you don't need to look into the future for stopping the process, so T is a stopping time".  I would like to learn to prove this in a more formal way, by using the definition above. Therefore, how can I explicitly see that the event** **$\{T \le n\}\in \mathscr F_n = \sigma(X_0,X_1, ...,X_n)$ in each case?**

These are the notes we are following:

people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mb13434/mart_thy_notes.pdf

Edit 1 : Following the suggestion for the first case:

Considering $n=1, $
$\mathscr F_1 = \sigma(X_0,X_1)$, $\{T\le 1\}=\{T=0\}\cup \{T=1\}$.  $ \{T=0\}$ is composed of  the events where I get my first head in the first toss, so $\{T=0\}= \{H\}$ , $ \{T=1\}$ is composed of  the events where I get my first head in the second toss  so $ \{T=1\}=\{TH\}$ and therefore  $\{T\le 1\}=\{H,TH\}$. How to continue from here? What is explicitly $\mathscr F_1$ and what are the values that $X_0$ and $X_1$ tan take?

Edit 2.

Actually I think the correct answer for n=1 of the first question is the following (I just hope someone can confirm the previous one was wrong) Since we are with n=1, $\mathscr F_1 = \sigma(X_0,X_1)$, $\Omega$ should be composed of two-toss events. Therefore: $\Omega=\{HH,HT,TT,TH\}$

$\{T=0\}= \{HH,HT\}$

$ \{T=1\}=\{TH\}$

$ \{T\le 1\}=\{TH,HH,HT\}$
To explicitly write  $\mathscr F_1$, Let $X_i(H)=1$, $X_i(T)=0$, $i=1,2 $, and I look at all possible preimages of singletons:

$X_0^{-1}(0)=\{TH,TT\}$

$X_0^{-1}(1)=\{HH,HT\}$

$X_1^{-1}(0)=\{HT,TT\}$

$X_1^{-1}(1)=\{HH,TH\}$

Since the sigma algebra generated  by $X_0$ and $X_1$ is the smallest one that make them measurable, I put all these preimages, their complements and unions in the sigma algebra, so:

$ \mathscr F_1= \sigma(X_0,X_1)=\{X_0^{-1}(0),X_0^{-1}(1),X_1^{-1}(0),X_1^{-1}(1),\Omega,\phi,\{HT,TH,TT\}, \{HH,TH,TT\}, \{HH,HT,TT\}, \{HH,HT,TH\}\}$ where I can explicitly see that $ \{T\le 1\}=\{TH,HH,HT\}\in \mathscr F_1$

I see that I still needed to take complements of the three-element sets and maybe even more sets are missing in the sigma-algebra. This rises the question of if there is an algorithmic way for listing them all without missing any? Maybe at the end I always get the power set?
Now how to generalize this to arbitrary n?

Comment: You should start by modeling the problem, i.e. what is $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F})_n, P)$, and what is the formal definition of $T$?

Comment: @stange The definition at the begnining is the only definition I have

Comment: There is some confusion, with some of the Wikipedia [stopping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time) definition not used by everyone (such as almost surely finite - your initial definition seems to allow actually infinite stopping times with non-zero probability).  But for a martingale you are probably interested in the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) where these and tighter requirements apply (such as finite expectation)

Comment: But how would you like to proof that $\{T\leq n\}\in\mathcal{F}_n$ when you have no idea what $\mathcal{F}_n$ actually is?

Comment: @stange These are the notes we are following by the way https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mb13434/mart_thy_notes.pdf  $\mathscr F_n$ is the natural filtration $ \sigma(X_1,X_2, ...,X_n)$ as I wrote at the end, which the notes say is assumed when no more information is given

Comment: @Henry Looks like my definition is the first one (discrete case ) but with an "$\le$" instead of an "$=$". But I read on these site that they are equivalent. You can also look at the notes I am following

Comment: Then you do have your filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$, with $X_j$ begin the outcome of the $j$-th coin toss for (1). Then start with thinking about what $\{T\leq 1\}$ is. What combinations of coin tosses are in this set and does it lie in $\mathcal{F}_1$? Then repeat this process with $n= 2$ to get the intuition behind and prove it in the end for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @stange  Considering $n=1, $$F_1 = \sigma(X_0,X_1)$, $\{T\le 1\}=\{T=0\}\cup \{T=1\}$.  $ \{T=0\}$ is composed of  the events where I get my first head in the first toss, so $\{T=0\}= \{H\}$ , $ \{T=1\}$ is composed of  the events where I get my first head in the second toss  so $ \{T=1\}=\{TH\}$ and therefore  $\{T\le 1\}=\{H,TH\}$. Is this correct or should I be considering only 2-toss events, that is: $\{T=0\}= \{HH, HT\}$, $ \{T=1\}=\{TH\}$ adn therefore $\{T\le 1\}=\{HH,HT,TH\}$? And how do I procede from here?

Comment: I mean how do I know if they are in $\mathscr F_1$,? I find  difficult to write  $\mathscr F_1$, since is composed of all pre-images of Borel sets, via the random variables $X_0$ and $X_1 $ , plus unions, intersection, complements and combinations

Comment: @stange I proved it for n=1 I guess, (adn for n=0) But how can I generalize this for n? It's not like I can list all the elements in the sigma algebra. For n=1 is already pretty long.

Answer (score 1):

These examples don't want you to prove anything. They want you to develop intuition.

- ${\cal F}_n$ is the amount of information available to you at time $n\,.$ Say, ${\cal F}_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}\,.$ That means at time $0$ you don't really know if an event happened or not. Later this event $A$ and its complement is in some ${\cal F}_n\,.$ That's when you know if it happened or not.
- The time *before* the first head is clearly not a stopping time because you know if it was *before* the first head only later and not at that "time".
- Typically, every random time that specifies when something happens for the
  *first* time is a stopping time.

More formally. Example 3 is the most common: By definition of
$$
T=\inf\{n:S_n=1\}
$$
we have
$$
\{T\le k\}=\bigcup_{n\le k}\{S_n=1\}\,.
$$
This shows that $\{T\le k\}\in{\cal F}_k$ and therefore $T$ is a stopping time.

About Example 1.

Let $S_n$ take value in $\{H,T\}$ and define
$$
T=\inf\{n:S_n=H\}
$$
the time of the first head. We know from the previous considerations that
$$
\{T\le k\}=\bigcup_{n\le k}\{S_n=H\}
$$
and that $T$ is a stopping time. The time before the first head is $T-1\,.$
We know
$$
\{T-1\le k\}=\{T\le k+1\}
$$
which is ${\cal F}_{k+1}-$ but not ${\cal F}_k$-measurable.

Comment: I understand the intuition, using the interpretation of sigma algebra as "the available information" but in my opinion is not a rigurous argument, just a nice interpretation. It would help to know how to explicitly prove at least one of them

Comment: How does it follow  from the union that $\{T \le k\} \in{\cal F}_k$ ?

Comment: I mean why is $\{S_n=1\} \in {\cal F}_k$?, if that is what you're using

Comment: I take the union over $n\le k$ and every $\{S_n=1\}$ is in ${\cal F}_n\,.$ Then we use that ${\cal F}_n\subset{\cal F}_k$ (increasing information with time). Needless to say that ${\cal F}_k$ is a $\sigma$-algebra closed under countable unions.

Comment: so why is $\{S_n=1\}\in {\cal F}_n$?

Comment: *Because* that's how ${\cal F}_n$ is *defined* (containing all information about $S_n$ at time $n$ and before $n$).

Comment: From your last edit, looks like the stopping time can always be defined in the form $\inf \{n: S_n=\text{<value of S_nthat stops the process >}\}$?

Comment: Not sure. This is however (as I said) the most typical example of a stopping time.